# Existence of an interval where a function is strictly existing

Tags: calculus

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous, differentiable function. Suppose that $f(x)=0$ for any $x\le 0$ and $f(x)>0$ otherwise. Is it true that there exists a positive real $a$ such that for any $x\in (0,a]$ we have that $f'(x)> 0$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If the mean value theorem always gives a $c \in (0,\infty) $ such that $f'(c) > 0$ is there an interval starting from $0$ such that $f' >0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242449/if-the-mean-value-theorem-always-gives-a-c-in-0-infty-such-that-fc)

Comment: can you check the title of your question @rmtf1111 ?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not true. Consider

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
0 & \mbox{for} &x\le 0\\
x^2\left(2+ \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)& \mbox{for} & x>0
\end{cases}$$

$f$ is continuous, differentiable and positive for $x>0$. However its derivative takes negative values on every interval $(0,a)$ for $a>0$.